# Shorten Query Retrieving Time Attendance Data

Tags: mysql

I have a code, which does the following:

- Get data from the `HrAttLogs` Table
- Input data from the `HrAttLogs` Table to the `HrAttLogsFormatted` Table

I would like to know whether the query below, which I will provide, can be improved? In terms of `Performance` and Speed.

```
SELECT 
    FingerId, 
    ShiftId, 
    DateIn, 
    DateOut, 
    ScanIn, 
    ScanOut, 
    WorkhourIn, 
    WorkhourOut, 
    TIME_IN, 
    TIME_OUT
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        i.FingerId,
        i.ShiftId,
        i.Date AS 'DateIn',
        o.Date AS 'DateOut',
        i.Time AS 'ScanIn',
        CASE WHEN o.Time != i.Time THEN o.Time END AS 'ScanOut',
        CASE
            WHEN i.Time < i.ShiftIn_2 THEN i.WorkhourIn_1
            WHEN i.Time < i.ShiftIn_3 THEN i.WorkhourIn_2
            WHEN i.Time > i.ShiftIn_1 THEN i.WorkhourIn_3
    END AS WorkhourIn,
        /* Added check for Date too.. the last checking is for any overlapping Date */
        CASE WHEN i.Status = 'Rolling' THEN
                CASE
                    WHEN i.DateOut = i.Date AND i.Time > i.ShiftOut_1 THEN i.WorkhourOut_2
                    WHEN i.DateOut = i.Date AND i.Time > i.ShiftOut_2 THEN i.WorkhourOut_3
                    WHEN i.DateOut = i.Date AND i.Time > i.ShiftOut_3 THEN i.WorkhourOut_1
                    WHEN i.DateOut > i.Date THEN i.WorkhourOut_3
                END
        ELSE
            CASE WHEN i.ShiftId != 'Rolling' THEN 
                    CASE WHEN i.DateOut = i.Date AND o.Time > i.ShiftOut_2 THEN i.WorkhourOut_3
                    ELSE i.WorkhourOut_2
                    END
                    WHEN i.DateOut = i.Date AND o.Time > i.ShiftOut_3 THEN i.WorkhourOut_1
            END
        END AS WorkhourOut,
        CASE
            WHEN i.Time < i.ShiftIn_2 THEN TIMEDIFF(i.Time, i.WorkhourIn_1)
            WHEN i.Time < i.ShiftIn_3 THEN TIMEDIFF(i.Time, i.WorkhourIn_2)
            WHEN i.Time > i.ShiftIn_1 THEN TIMEDIFF(i.Time, i.WorkhourIn_3)
        END AS 'TIME_IN',
        CASE WHEN o.Time != i.Time THEN 
            CASE WHEN i.Status = 'Rolling' THEN
                CASE WHEN o.Time > i.ShiftOut_3 THEN 
                    CASE WHEN o.Time > i.ShiftOut_1 THEN 
                        CASE WHEN o.Time > i.ShiftOut_2 THEN TIMEDIFF(o.Time, i.WorkhourOut_2)
                        ELSE TIMEDIFF(o.Time, i.WorkhourOut_1)
                        END
                    ELSE TIMEDIFF(o.Time, i.WorkhourOut_1)
                    END 
                ELSE TIMEDIFF(o.Time, i.WorkhourOut_3)
                END
            ELSE
                CASE WHEN i.Status != 'Rolling' THEN
                    CASE WHEN o.Time > i.ShiftOut_1 THEN
                        CASE WHEN o.Time > i.ShiftOut_2 THEN TIMEDIFF(o.Time, i.WorkhourOut_1)
                        ELSE TIMEDIFF(o.Time, i.WorkhourOut_2)
                        END
                    END
                END
            END
        END AS 'TIME_OUT',
        i.ShiftIn_1,
        i.ShiftIn_2,
        i.ShiftIn_3,
        i.ShiftOut_1,
        i.ShiftOut_2,
        i.ShiftOut_3,
        i.WorkhourIn_2,
        i.WorkhourIn_3,
        i.WorkhourOut_2,
        i.WorkhourOut_3,
        i.Status
    FROM
        ( /* INSERT here */
                SELECT 
                    i.FingerId,
                    fs.ShiftId,
                CASE WHEN i.Status = 0 THEN
                    MIN(i.Date)
                END AS 'Date',
--         MIN(i.Date) AS 'Date',
                /* Added CASE expression to deal with overlapping attendance Date */
                CASE WHEN i.Status = 0 AND MIN(i.Time) >= '19:00:00' 
                     THEN DATE(DATE_ADD(i.Date, INTERVAL + 1 DAY)) 
                ELSE 
                    DATE(DATE_ADD(i.Date, INTERVAL + s.DayOut DAY)) 
                END AS 'DateOut', 
                    CASE WHEN i.Status = 0 THEN
                        i.Time
                    END AS 'Time',
--           MIN(i.Time) AS 'Time',
                    i.Status,
          s.ShiftIn_1,
          s.ShiftIn_2,
          s.ShiftIn_3,
          s.ShiftOut_1,
          s.ShiftOut_2,
          s.ShiftOut_3,
          s.WorkhourIn_1,
          s.WorkhourIn_2,
          s.WorkhourIn_3,
          s.WorkhourOut_1,
          s.WorkhourOut_2,
          s.WorkhourOut_3
        FROM HrAttLogs AS i
        INNER JOIN HrEmployee AS fs ON fs.FingerId = i.FingerId
        INNER JOIN HrEmployeeShift AS s ON s.Id = fs.ShiftId
        WHERE 
            i.Time >= s.ShiftIn_1
            AND i.Date >= '2020-04-07'
            AND i.Date <= '2020-04-09' 
            AND i.MachineIp = '10.20.20.73'
        GROUP BY
                        i.Id,
            i.FingerId, 
            i.Date 
        ) AS i
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT
                o.FingerId,
                CASE WHEN o.Status = 1 THEN
                    MAX(o.Date)
                END AS 'Date',
                CASE WHEN o.Status = 1 THEN
                    MAX(o.Time)
                END AS 'Time',
                o.Status
            FROM
                HrAttLogs AS o
            WHERE
                o.Date >= '2020-04-07'
                AND o.Date <= '2020-04-09'
                AND o.MachineIp = '10.20.20.73'
            GROUP BY
                o.Id,
                o.FingerId,
                o.Date
            ORDER BY
                Date ASC,
                Status ASC
        ) AS o ON i.FingerId = o.FingerId 
        AND o.Date = i.DateOut 
        AND o.Time >= '00:00:00'
    ) AS q
WHERE
    FingerId = 61
    AND FingerId IS NOT NULL
    AND ShiftId IS NOT NULL
    AND DateIn IS NOT NULL
    AND DateOut IS NOT NULL
    AND ScanIn  IS NOT NULL
    AND WorkhourIn IS NOT NULL
    AND WorkhourOut IS NOT NULL
    AND TIME_IN IS NOT NULL
    AND TIME_OUT IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    q.FingerId ASC,
    DateIn ASC
```

For more details, I save it [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vhJQ1tFyzWitnJn4cDnarW/2)